# Is there any legitimate reason to swap the order of declarations in C?

Tags: c

In some code I'm maintaining, I came across this:

```c
int lsm6ds3_common_resume(struct lsm6ds3_data *cdata);
int lsm6ds3_common_suspend(struct lsm6ds3_data *cdata);

#ifdef CONFIG_PM
int lsm6ds3_common_suspend(struct lsm6ds3_data *cdata);
int lsm6ds3_common_resume(struct lsm6ds3_data *cdata);
#endif /* CONFIG_PM */
```

This appears to swap the order of these declarations depending on the value of `CONFIG_PM`.  Does this do anything useful, or can it be safely deleted?

Comment: It wouldn't. Perhaps there used to be other code in between, and they never noticed they had two sets of declarations, and then they removed the code that was in between and still didn't notice.

Comment: When maintaining code, never implicitly assume that the code makes sense.

Comment: Repeating the declarations doesn't make them any more useful.  You can delete one set — and it may as well be the set in the `#ifdef` block since the other set ensures the functions are always declared.